# Need large integers and floats. Trouble with long long int and long double

Tags: c, gcc, long-integer, long-double, long-long

I am a sort of newbie to programming (actually coming back to it after a gap of 20 yrs :) ). I am trying to make a program for a question on project euler, to find sum of all prime numbers under 2 million.
I am trying to use the Eratosthenes sieve algorithm.
I am using code::blocks with GNU GCC compiler.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define L 2000000
 int main()
 {
     unsigned long long int i, j, n, num[L], sum = 0;
     for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
         num[i] = i + 1;

     for (j = 2; j*j <=L; j++)
         {
             for (n = j; n*j<=L; n++)
                 {
                     num[n * j - 1] = 0;
                 }
         }
     for (i = 1; i < L; i++)
         {
             if (num[i] != 0)
                 {
                     printf("%llu\n",num[i]);
                     sum = sum + num[i];
                 }
         }
     printf("%llu\n", sum);
     return 0;
 }
```

The program works for all values of L below 1000000, but stops working above that. Also I get warning about the long long int as follows:

```
***||=== Build file: Debug in 2MILLIONPRIMESUM (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

***E:\Code Blocks Projects\2MILLIONPRIMESUM\main.c||In function 'main':|

E:\Code Blocks Projects\2MILLIONPRIMESUM\main.c|22|warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat=]|

E:\Code Blocks Projects\2MILLIONPRIMESUM\main.c|22|warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]|******
```

I get similar warnings when trying to use "long double" etc. Is this a problem with the compiler, that it cannot handle long long and long double?

The above code works without any warning (only for L <=1000000) on GDB online compiler.
Request everyone to advise me on the above issues.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You need to look up the format specifiers for `long long` and `long double` in `printf()`.

Comment: `man stdint` and `man inttypes`

Comment: The array needs 2 million 8byte values on the limited, default stack... Not gonna fit without special handling...

Comment: `unsigned long long int num[2000000]` requires ~15 megabytes of space. The stack is unlikely to be that large by default. An alternative is to make that variable global or static.

Comment: @user207421 The code in the question should not result in any warnings about format specifies. The values being printed are of type `unsigned long long`, and `%ull` is correct. Vinayak, are you sure the code in the question is the same as the code that gave you those warnings? (There are several visible edits, but none of them change the code.)

Comment: Thank you everyone. Kieth Thompson, the code does not give these warning on online compilers, but somehow Codeblocks +GNU GCC is not very comfortable with it :)

Comment: Assuming the code in the question matches the code you're feeding to gcc, you must be  using a very old version of gcc. The type `unsigned long long` and the `%llu` format specifier were both introduced in 1999 edition of the ISO C standard. I think that gcc introduced `long long` and `unsigned long long` as an extension before it started recognizing `%llu`. What does `gcc --version` print? Can you upgrade your gcc installation?

Comment: And to be clear, gcc recognizes %llu` and other format specifiers for the purpose of generating warning messages. The actual implementation is in the runtime library, which is a different component.

Comment: I'm still curious what version of gcc you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, `2000000 * sizeof(long long)` is too large of an array to fit on the stack; confidence is high that this is the root cause of the issue.

That said, the code works nicely when we add the dynamic memory allocation of `num` as shown below in the line having `malloc()`.  We also added code to ensure the memory allocation was successful.  If not, a `printf()` is there to alert the user, and then the program exits harmlessly.

This code was compiled and run/checked by me before posting.

EDIT:  I ran one more test just now with `sum` as type `double` -- the final answer is still the same: `142913828922`.  This tends to support the notion that the code is working per design and requirement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define L 2000000

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int i, j, n, sum = 0;
    unsigned long long int *num = malloc( L * sizeof(unsigned long long int));

    if(!num)
    {
        printf("malloc() failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
        num[i] = i + 1;

    for (j = 2; j*j <=L; j++)
    {
        for (n = j; n*j<=L; n++)
        {
            num[n * j - 1] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i < L; i++)
    {
        if (num[i] != 0)
        {
            printf("%llu\n",num[i]);
            sum = sum + num[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%llu\n", sum);

    /* As you malloc(), so shall you free()! (thank you Fe2O3): */
    free(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
...
...
1999733
1999771
1999799
1999817
1999819
1999853
1999859
1999867
1999871
1999889
1999891
1999957
1999969
1999979
1999993
142913828922
```

This 2nd version may interest you:  per discussion with Fe2O3 in comments, it was revealed that the `num` array need *not* occupy a `long long` data type;  that the range of `num` array will fit neatly into a 32-bit int.

Furthermore, upon reflection, it was realized that such a change invites a considerable space savings.  So much so that *perhaps the adapted `num` array may now fit on the stack!*

This notion seems to be born out per the runnable code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vf8fYrM37).

Conspicuously absent from the code is any hint of `malloc()`, and yet we're getting competent results per the featured `Output`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define L 2000000

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int sum = 0;
    unsigned int i, j, n, num[L]; 

    for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
        num[i] = i + 1;

    for (j = 2; j*j <=L; j++)
    {
        for (n = j; n*j<=L; n++)
        {
            num[n * j - 1] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i < L; i++)
    {
        if (num[i] != 0)
        {
            if(i > L-200) /* just print last XX of array*/
                printf("%llu\n",num[i]);
            sum = sum + num[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%llu\n", sum);
    printf("sizeof(int): %u\nsizeof(num): %u\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(num));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1999817
1999819
1999853
1999859
1999867
1999871
1999889
1999891
1999957
1999969
1999979
1999993
142913828922
sizeof(int): 4
sizeof(num): 8000000
```

Nice thing about Stackverflow community is that they'll bring ideas to the table that challenge and grow you.  Both Fe2O3 and Jonathan Leffler mentioned using bits for even more space savings. (Wut?)  At last I've worked it out...

Here is version 3.0 for the world -- only puts about 240K on the stack -- nice! That's a long way from the 2 terrabytes we started with. (j/k -- was actually 2M * 64bits = 15.25MB)

Runnable code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/M6jzd8xx5).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* memset */

#define L 2000000

/* These one-line bit ops are a compromise between a macro and a function */
static void clear_bit(unsigned char *x, int bitNum) { *x &= ~(1L << bitNum); }
static int test_bit(unsigned char x, int bitNum) { return !!(x & (1L << (bitNum))); }
static void set_bit(unsigned char *x, int bitNum) { *x |= (1L << bitNum); } /* unused */

int main()
{
    unsigned long i=8, j, n;
    unsigned char bits[L/8];
    unsigned long long int sum = 0;

    /* Set all the bits of the array to 1.  Replaces step in old code
    * where we filled the array with num = index + 1 */
    memset(bits, 255, sizeof(bits));

    /* This is the section where we *disqualify* non-prime entries by 
    * clearing the related bit.  Formerly we set the index to zero.*/
    for (j = 2; j*j <= L; j++)
    {
        for (n = j; n*j <= L; n++)
        {
            long num = n * j;
            clear_bit(&bits[num/8], num%8);
        }
    }
    /* In this section we'll do a print out and get the sum as before... */
    for (i = 2; i < L; i++)
    {
        if (test_bit(bits[i/8], (i%8))  != 0)
        {
            if(i > L-200) /* just print last XX of array*/
                printf("%lu\n", i );
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    /*should say 142913828922  (142,913,828,922)*/
    printf("%lld\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1999817
1999819
1999853
1999859
1999867
1999871
1999889
1999891
1999957
1999969
1999979
1999993
142913828922
```

Here is version 4.0 -- only puts about 122K on the stack.
The bit array is halved since v3.0.  Thanks again to the
SO community for the inspiration -- please see comments
for more, and the algo optimizations from Fe2O3.

Runnable code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/68MGzxEoY).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* memset */

#define L 2000000

static void clear_bit(unsigned char *x, int bitNum) { *x &= ~(1L << bitNum); }
static int test_bit(unsigned char x, int bitNum) { return !!(x & (1L << (bitNum))); }

int main()
{
    unsigned long i, j, n;
    unsigned char bits[L/16];    /* Only 125,000 bytes! */
    unsigned long long sum = 0;

    /* Set all the bits of the array to 1. */
    memset(bits, 255, sizeof(bits));

    /* Disqualify non-prime entries by clearing the related bit.  
    * Small note on how bit array is accessed:
     In an odd-numbers-only bit buffer, addressing is:
        bits[0] represents numbers: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11,13,15
        bits[1] represents numbers: 17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31
        bits[2] represents numbers: 33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47 
        ...
        Hence, the math is: 
        bit array offset   = number/16;
        Representative bit = (number%16)/2
    */
    for (j = 2; j*j <= L; j++)
    {
        for (n = j; n*j <= L; n++)
        {
            long num = n * j; 
            long offset = num/16;
            if(num%2) /* if odd */
                clear_bit(&bits[offset], (num%16)>>1 );
        }
    }
    /* Print out and sum: 2 will be a special case because it is the only
    * even prime number in the universe. Per our algo, we store no even 
    * numbers.  Hence, 2 (and its printing, if desired) is done manually. */
    sum = 2;  /* Primes start here */
    for(i = 3; i < L; i+=2) /* Now process the remaining primes... */
    {
        long offset = i/16;
        if(test_bit(bits[offset], (i%16)>>1 ) != 0)
        {
            if(i > L-200) /* just print last XX of array*/
            {
                printf("%lu\n", i );
            }
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    /*should say 142913828922  (142,913,828,922). */
    printf("%llu\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1999817
1999819
1999853
1999859
1999867
1999871
1999889
1999891
1999957
1999969
1999979
1999993
142913828922
```

My 2 cents for version 5.0:

- accept command line argument for `L`, defaults to `2000000`
- only iterate over odd multiples of odd numbers (40% less time)
- use `unsigned long` for all computations
- `bits` array now allocated and initialized to `0`, indicates *composite numbers*
- simpler bit set and test functions.

Chqrlie.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void set_bit(unsigned char *x, int bitNum) { *x |= 1 << bitNum; }
static int test_bit(unsigned char x, int bitNum) { return (x >> bitNum) & 1; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long L = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 2000000;
    unsigned long i, j, n;
    unsigned char *bits = calloc(1, L / 16 + 1);    /* Only 125,000 bytes! */
    unsigned long long sum;

    if (!bits) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* Disqualify non-prime entries by clearing the related bit.
     * Small note on how bit array is accessed:
       in an odd-numbers-only bit buffer, addressing is:
       bits[0] represents numbers: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11,13,15
       bits[1] represents numbers: 17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31
       bits[2] represents numbers: 33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47
       ...
       Hence, the math is:
       bit array offset   = number / 16;
       representative bit = (number % 16) / 2
     */
    for (j = 3; j * j <= L; j += 2)
    {
        for (n = j * j; n <= L; n += 2 * j)
        {
            unsigned long offset = n / 16;
            set_bit(&bits[offset], (n % 16) >> 1);
        }
    }
    /* Print out and sum: 2 will be a special case because it is the only
     * even prime number in the universe. Per our algo, we store no even
     * numbers.  Hence, 2 (and its printing, if desired) is done manually. */
    sum = 2;  /* Primes start here */
    for (i = 3; i <= L; i += 2) /* Now process the remaining primes... */
    {
        unsigned long offset = i / 16;
        if (!test_bit(bits[offset], (i % 16) >> 1))
        {
            sum += i;
            if (i > L - 200) /* just print last XX of array*/
            {
                printf("%lu\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
    /*should say 142913828922  (142,913,828,922). */
    printf("%llu\n", sum);
    free(bits);
    return 0;
}
```

Output (13ms total time):

```
1999817
1999819
1999853
1999859
1999867
1999871
1999889
1999891
1999957
1999969
1999979
1999993
142913828922
```

Comment: @Fe2O3 -- 100%  -- I have updated for the world, and credited you.  Thank you for your kind delivery.

Comment: Further, this algorithm fills array with values from (ideally 0) 1 to 'n' million. Array elements of `unsigned long` would be sufficient to range up to over 4 billion... Only `sum` needs to be `(unsigned) long long`.

Comment: @Fe2O3 -- this is true.  I noticed that when I observed the output, lol.  I hope OP notices your comment -- or shall I update once more?  There is, after all, a potential savings of ~7.5 MB of memory... on the other hand, it's a comfort when I can keep OP's code close to their original -- showing how close they were -- adding only a small tweek to get running....

Comment: Can't say how the OP will act. Yesterday OP posted related question... Funny! If OP's ceiling **was** only "2 million", s/he might have had success using smaller datatype for array. (Compiler specific stack allocation.) It's up to you to decide if you want to make the effort. (Me? I would have used "8 bits to a byte" to designate which (ascending) values remain after the sieve operations... `unsigned char bits[ 125000 ];` More operations, but better caching.) Cheers! :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 -- yes!  This occurred to me too - the potential success on smaller data type without malloc() - and this question would have never been asked.   Hmmm...

Comment: Note that modern Unix systems default to an 8 MiB stack; Windows defaults to a 1MiB stack.  You only need 1 bit per odd number in the sieve, so you can easily save a lot of storage.  You use bit operations to record that an odd multiple of the prime you just found is not prime.  Requires care, but saves lots of space.

Comment: Going beyond OP's code (and problem), this may be worth noting: The algorithm fills a large array with "flags", then iteratively "knocks down" those flags that are multiples of primes. The iteration of `n * 3` resets lots of array elements (1/3rd). Similarly, `n * 5` does the same for 1/5th of the array. There's no point to executing the sweep of `n * 15` (133,00 steps for an array of 2 million candidates). There's no point for looping thousands of times to reset candidates that have already been cleared... Something to do, eh? `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 -- I'm still working out where you said 'unsigned char bits[ 125000 ];'  But I think it just hit me as I read your new comment just now, and it's coded in my head.  Going to see if I can pound it out now...

Comment: @gregspears FYI: This "elaboration" occurred to me during a walk when, for reasons still unclear, "FizzBuzz" popped into my head... Hahaha... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 -- UPDATED -- optimization is a good point and arguably applicable. You can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YYeGGhbvc) that by commenting and uncommenting the test_bit() line that we're visiting multiples 7X more than we need to.   I can find plenty of optimization methods, but so far nothing that is less expensive than all the factor-revisiting it's doing now.

Comment: @gregspears Better! `:-)` I've spent an hour hacking a copy your Godbolt code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/reb6orPav). As said, "_something to do, eh?_" `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 -- Wow!  As soon as I saw `memset( .. 0xAA ..)` for only odd bits, I knew I missed more than I thought I did, lol!   And running through only odd bits in the loop?  Pretty brilliant stuff, you.  *Of course -- why didn't I think of that, howl!*  Good job!

Comment: @gregspears Thanks... Just having fun... Back from an outing during which I realised another "speed up". `for( uint32_t n = i+i+i; n <= L; n += i+i ) {` <== new version of MY line 14 (Don't want to clog-up Godbolt with another archived version.) Result of this "double increment": `iterations: 1744442`,,, (About 1/2 as many as previous version.) `:-)` Reason: _odd * odd ==> odd_ but _odd * even ==> even_ No use executing body of `for()` for even multiples (resetting those bits already known to be reset).

Comment: @gregspears I think I'm done now. [last revision](https://godbolt.org/z/TMfbTG55d) Found another fairly simple 'tweak' to reduce processing time. (Comments in code.) Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 -- of course it's awesome!  Even have your own `lltoa()`  -- just great.  OK, I *thought* I was done with this, but you mentioned "doubling the density" of flag bits per Johnathan Leffler.  I totally missed that the bit array could be halved once more by dumping all the even bit representations.  It's proving not as easy as I thought cuz addressing, but I got close in a hurry....

Comment: @gregspears "_Are we having fun, yet?_" `:-)` ... Well... Yes, I suppose so... `:-)` Looking forward to seeing those 2'000'000 integer values being represented in only 125'000 bytes! The OP's clogged-up "stack" will again have an abundance of clear air to breathe... `:-)` Best wishes! And have a happy Easter!

Comment: @Fe2O3  -- thanks!  You have a great Easter, too.  BTW, this is turning out to be a little more difficult than I thought it would be.  But verrrrry close now.  I was able to get a basic method for representing all the odd numbers with the odd-number-only bit array( a big hurdle for me ).  But now applying the method to the prime number program is just not working out, lol.  All the best...

Comment: `for (j = 2; j*j <= L; j++) { for (n = j; n*j <= L; n++) ...` is inefficient: `j` should start at 3 and get incremented by 2, `n` should be incremented by 2 and there will be no need for the `if(num%2)` test, which is almost always mispredicted (hence slow).

Comment: @gregspears Congratulations! You can take the weekend off, now... `:-)` ... Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: @chqrlie - thx for your input. If this improvement cycle continues (and it may, lol) now that we've maximized memory usage, certainly algo improvement is next.  Have you seen Fe2O3's links to godbolt?  Some of it gets over my head.  But I'm looking at synthesizing Fe2O3's inputs with your suggestion(s) and adapting it to this code.  I'm slightly reluctant because -- unlike the memory-saving code -- I'm not fully able to originate it.  I mean, it's kind of like taking other people's code and passing it as my own; that's not *great* to me, lol.  But, if I could synth something original...

Comment: @Fe2O3 - thanks! Not sure I will take time off, because coding ( besides keeping the brain young ) keeps my mind *off* the issues and trials and tribulations of life.  Anyway, thanks for your mentoring and support and feedback on all this.  Been great learning and I'd like to think OP is enjoying, and that it will help people for another generation, or a long-ish time anyway. hehehe

Comment: @gregspears Projects like this keep one's brain at its prime! ... (Sorry... *facepalm with groan*)...

Comment: @Fe2O3 - my first lol all day, thank you.  $:-<>    I do need this practice, because my mind is like a *sieve*.  ( Hmmm? yas? lol )

Comment: @chqrlie  -- nice!  Notable (75%) reduction in setup_passes from [4.0](https://godbolt.org/z/9nh77Ye1z)  to [5.0](https://godbolt.org/z/jKaEdxPve).  Cmd line option *is* a nice touch.  [This](https://godbolt.org/z/xYccfcP81) tests that option -- test passed.  ;-)

Comment: @gregspears Well done. Your work and effort deserves the rep points! ... Pedantry **for the record**: My little `memset( .. 0xAA ..)` was a misstep, wandering away from a proper implemention of the Sieve algorithm... This "time saving" shortcut introduced _unsubstantiated_ "intuitive foreknowledge" (about how all values divisible by 2 might have been represented.) A mathematician would have kittens! [A short video blowing up intuition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mfk_L4Nx2ZI) Cheers! `:-)` (_mind like a sieve..._ Hmmm... Go and stand in the corner for an hour!... `:-)`)

Comment: @Fe2O3 - Thanks!  Nice to see you like Numberphile (which makes sense).  I have binge-watched that.  It's hard to find one *not* interesting ...